# Argument principle: number of zeroes of $f(z)=\cos(z)-1 +z^2/2$ in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, residue-calculus

I am trying to work on this old qual exam.

Here is the question:

> Find the number of roots (counting multiplicities) of the function
>   $$f(z)=\cos(z)-1 + \frac{z^2}{2}$$  inside the domain $\vert z \vert <1$.

My work: I first thought of Rouché's theorem. But then I figured that
$f(z)=z^4\left(\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{z^2}{6!}+\cdots\right)$. So $f(z)=z^4 g(z)$ for some analytic
function $g(z)$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$. And then I used the argument principle to conclude that the number of zeroes is $4$. Is this correct?

Also, how do I know for sure that there are no other zeroes of $g$ inside the unit disk centered at $0$.
Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: Click on your username to see your profile. Look back at your previous questions that people submitted answers for. If you find any of the responses helpful, I suggest up voting them by clicking on the up arrow next to the number at the top left of their answer. If one particular submission answers your question "best", accept it by clicking on the check mark underneath the up/down vote button.

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to help you get the most out of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic in the domain $D:=\{z:|z|<1\}$, the Argument Principle says that the number of zeros of $f$ in $D$ is given by $${1\over 2\pi i}\int_D {f'(z)\over f(z)}\,dz,$$ which we will compute via the Residue Theorem.

First, expanding about $z=0$, $${f'(z)\over f(z)}=\frac{4}{z}-\frac{z}{15}+\frac{z^3}{6300}+\frac{z^5}{189000}+\cdots,$$
so by the Residue Theorem,
$${1\over 2\pi i}\int_D {f'(z)\over f(z)}\,dz=\text{Res}(f'(z)/f(z),0)=4.$$

Hence, $f(z)$ has 4 zeros (counting multiplicities) in $D$.

Comment: I still don't see how the last integral is equal to $8\pi i$. Can you please explain a little more?. Thanks.

Comment: The earlier integral I computed with *Mathematica* without much thought and got $4$. Perhaps the revision is clearer.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. Plus I was actually able to do this with Rouche's theorem as well. It never hurts to know two methods. Like one of my Professors once said, if you can prove it in two ways, it must be really really true. :).Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you only take the residue at $0$ to calculate the integral? Don't all of the zeroes of $f$ need to be considered?

Comment: @user54755  How did you solve this using Rouche's theorem?

Comment: This computation only shows that $f(z)$ has a zero of multiplicity $4$ at $z=0$.  By only calculating the residue at $z=0$ you have implicitly taken your contour to be an arbitrarily small circuit about the origin.  You should have taken it to be the circle $|z| = 1$.