# Number of zeros of the complex function in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VP}{V.P.}
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AC}{AC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\BB}{B}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RHO}{\rho}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\CCC}{C^1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\contt}{C}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PCC}{PC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LL}{L}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VEC}{vec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EXP}{exp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\COS}{cos}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SIN}{sin}
\newcommand{\ph}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\inth}{\Int_{-h_k}^0}
\newcommand{\teta}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
%\renewcommand{\L}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\<}{\leq}
\renewcommand{\>}{\geq}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits}
\newcommand{\Sup}{\sup\limits}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\renewcommand{\ae}{\stackrel{\mathrm{a.e.}}{=}}
\newcommand{\mh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\bh}{\mathbf h}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbf N}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm{d}t}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textup{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\textup{y}}
%\newcommand{\w}{\textup{w}}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\ti}{\times}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\del}{\delta}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\renewcommand{\O}{\Omega}
\newcommand{\til}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}
\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\wD}{\widehat{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\imp}{\implies}
\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}
$
Consider the function $f(z)=10 \sin (z^{2019})-z.$ I'd like to find the number of zeros of $f$ in the unit disk $D=\left\{z\in\C:~|z|\<1\right\}.$

I've found the similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303406/number-of-complex-roots) and can't understand why
$$
|\sin z|\>\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\quad\forall z=x+iy\in\C:~|z|=1.\tag{1}
$$
Namely, why $\sqrt{(\e^{2y}-4+\e^{-2y})+(4-2\cos(2x))}\>\sqrt 2$? Lagrange multipliers method for function $g(x,y)=(\e^{2y}-4+\e^{-2y})+(4-2\cos(2x))$ gives the system which is really hard to solve.

Found another approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274690/argument-principle-number-of-zeroes-of-fz-cosz-1-z2-2-in-the-unit-disk) but we need ($f(z)\ne 0$ if $|z|=1$) in order to use Argument Principle.

Comment: I don't think you really need all those `DeclareMathOperator`s and `newcommand`s.

Comment: It looks true but not obvious that with real variables $x^2+y^2=1 \implies e^{2y}+e^{-2y} - 2 \cos(2x) \geq 2$. I don't see how the $\pm 4$ might help.

Comment: Where is the $2019$ power? Looks like it is $z^{2019}$ and then sine; is that correct?

Comment: @Conrad My bad, fixed.

Comment: @Arthur why it's bad if I write these commands but not use it?

Comment: I don't think it is. It is only curious.

Comment: (It does make it a little more difficult to edit when you have to scroll past all those lines.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to apply Rouche and conclude that there are precisely $2019$ zeroes (and using that $|z^{2019}|=1$), one needs to prove that $|\sin w| >1/10, |w|=1$ since then for $|z|=1$ one has $$|10\sin z^{2019}| > |10\sin z^{2019}-(10\sin z^{2019}-z)|=1$$

But if $w=x+iy, x^2+y^2=1$ one has $|\sin w|=(\sin^2 x+\sinh^2 y)^{1/2} \ge \max (|\sin x|, |\sinh y|)$ and using that for $|x| \le \pi/2, |\sin x| \ge 2|x|/\pi >4|x|/7$, the inequality follows for $|x|>7/40$; on the other hand $2|\sinh y| =e^{|y|}-e^{-|y|}\ge 1+|y|-1=|y|$ so $|\sinh y| \ge |y|/2$ hence the inequality holds for $|y|>1/5$. Since $x^2+y^2=1$ implies at least one the above inequalities $|x|>7/40, |y|>1/5$ holds we are done!